# After I get all variables that inside .env file how to replace the value of any variable of them if it defined in bash or system

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, webpack, dotenv

In nodejs project if

- I have `index.js` file that contains the following

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/.env') });

console.log(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE);
```

- And I have `.env` file that contains the following

```
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=a
...and more environment variables
```

- And I go to bash and I run the following command

```sh
export ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=b && node ./index.js
```

The value of `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` that I will get after I run app is  `b` (which defiend in bash)

---

But in webpack project if

- I have `index.js` file that contains the following

```
console.log(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE);
```

- And I have `.env` file same as the previous one ( that in nodejs project )
- And my webpack configuration as the following

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/.env') });

module.exports = {
  ...
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/index.js'),
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed)
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
};
```

- And I go to bash and I run the following command

```sh
export ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=b && yarn start
```

The value of `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` that I will get after I run app is  `a` (which defiend in `.env` file) not `b` (which defiend in bash)

> But the value of `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` that I want to get is `b` (which defiend in bash) not `a` (which defiend in `.env` file). And if `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` doesn't defined in bash or system the value that I want to get is `a` (which defiend in `.env` file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsed` that is returned by `dotenv.config` is what was loaded from your `path` (`.env`) and does not take into account what's already in your environment (i.e. `process.env`). The `config` method assigns to `process.env` based on `parsed` (but will not override).

Passing only the variables you intended to use in Webpack from `process.env` should fix your issue:

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
})
```

Comment: if I have only one environment variable your solution will be good for this case. But if I have many environment variables your solution will be not good for this case.

Comment: remove `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` from my answer and you'll ship everything to webpack but also potentially sensitive information about your process

Answer (score -1):

This use case has already been reported and discussed here , https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/199 . Or you can use this if that fits your requirement https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-override

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync('.env.override'))
for (var k in envConfig) {
 process.env[k] = envConfig[k]
}
```

The above example is referred from the dotenv-override registry

Comment: They are not asking to override the environment but actually use what's defined by the environment and not in their .env file

Comment: That is exactly what i had understood , may be i hadn't detailed that in this answer , The second link have an example like what you have given above .If there is no override's in the bash they want to use the default env variable isn't it